# How to Identify Multiple Insert Rows from Single Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transaction

Is there method to identify multiple rows from single insert transaction?

IdentityId will uniquely identify each row. If 2000 rows were inserted from one insert transaction, how would I identify this? Is there like a BatchId() Identifier or TransactionId() reserved word? Using ETL default getdate() will not work, sometimes a transaction could span over milliseconds.

EG:

```
begin transaction
insert into dbo.Test2
select * from Test where ColumnA = 'etc...; 
commit transaction
```

Refraining from using pattern below, may be inefficient, is there a  reserved keyword for batch transaction identifier?

```
select @MaxTransactionId = (select Max(transactionId) from dbo.Test2), 
TransactionId = @MaxTransactionId + 1,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)
It is simple and the sequence value always increases in one way

```
-- you only need to create it once
create sequence seq as int start with 1
go

-- you can then do this
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @BatchID int = next value for seq
INSERT INTO dbo.Test2
       SELECT *, @BatchID AS [batch_id]
       FROM Test;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: using Sequence instead of CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() will make sure even the sql server restarts, your next batch_id is still bigger than the previous batch_id. While current_transaction_id cannot guarantee you this.

Comment: Yep not in a position to test but the answers here would indicate that IDs are reused after restart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002700/sys-dm-tran-current-transaction-how-unique-is-transaction-id

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your use case, I'll suggest just storing it in the table itself in a simple, albeit klunky, way. If its for a one-off type activity it should work fine:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @date DATETIMEOFFSET(7) = SYSDATETIME()
INSERT INTO dbo.Test2
       SELECT *, RAND() AS [batch_id], @date AS [batch_timestamp]
       FROM Test;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Now each transaction will have a unique `RAND()` **and** a unique timestamp value to group the rows together.

Using both the `RAND()` and timestamp is somewhat redundant, so pick whichever one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() + ROW_NUMBER()`:

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> -- ② Integers table
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> with
>   p0(i) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
> , p1(i) as (select 1 from p0 as a, p0 as b, p0 as c, p0 as d, p0 as e)--1K rows
> , p2(i) as (select 1 from p1 as a, p1 as b)--1M rows
> select row_number() over(order by i) as val
> into integers
> from p2
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1048576 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> create table test2(f1 int, rowid varchar(50))
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> begin transaction;
> insert into test2
> select top 10 val, (cast(current_transaction_id() as varchar(10))
>                    + '/'
>                    + cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(10))) row_id
> from   integers
> where  val > 100;
> commit transaction;
>
> begin transaction;
> insert into test2
> select top 10 val, (cast(current_transaction_id() as varchar(10))
>                    + '/'
>                    + cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(10))) row_id
> from   integers
> where  val > 100;
> commit transaction;
>
> select * from test2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  f1 | rowid       
> --: | :-----------
> 101 | 491953811/1 
> 102 | 491953811/2 
> 103 | 491953811/3 
> 104 | 491953811/4 
> 105 | 491953811/5 
> 106 | 491953811/6 
> 107 | 491953811/7 
> 108 | 491953811/8 
> 109 | 491953811/9 
> 110 | 491953811/10
> 101 | 491953828/1 
> 102 | 491953828/2 
> 103 | 491953828/3 
> 104 | 491953828/4 
> 105 | 491953828/5 
> 106 | 491953828/6 
> 107 | 491953828/7 
> 108 | 491953828/8 
> 109 | 491953828/9 
> 110 | 491953828/10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=caef3d88219f3a8e761267aae2ba26ac)*